# Sometimes my page can't access PHP session variable

Tags: php, session

I am working on E-commerce Web Application, which is having users and permissions to them.. So according to their permission,

For Ex: I am storing variable `$chk = 'write'` or `$chk = 'read'` on session and my condition is

```
if ($chk == 'write')
{
   // some function here to modify the page & its content
   // If true, then display SAVE button to save all changes made.
}
```

But, Sometimes my page cant access this variable, the value of `$chk` is unknown hence its not displaying SAVE button. But, it shows the button after refreshing the page or visiting sometime later. Can anyone help me to solve this.. Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems more appropriate for Stack Overflow as this is not a design problem but a code error.  But, chances are this Q would get closed there too, need more code that is surrounding your condition.  Chances are you aren't calling `session_start()` appropriately.

Comment: how are you storing them in the session? how are you pulling them out of the session?  As cspray says need more code.  Also are we talking single server? multiple servers behind Load Balancer. Sessions stored on server , or in database?

Comment: Please add relevant code. The block shown gives no insight e.g. how do you assign current value to '$chk' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session variables in PHP need to be stored in the `$_SESSION` magic variable to persist them across multiple pages. To ensure that a page has access to the session, you also need to call `session_start()` on each page.

In this case, changing `$chk` to `$_SESSION['chk']` and adding `session_start()` at the top of each page will probably do the trick.